# Initialize store based on query string params

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My application can be accessed with query string parameters, that contain some initial settings e.g. `?accountId=PL123454252` .

When it is done, I need to initialize store i.e. put associated account object from the query string into the store.

Initially I did it with a component wrapped in e.g. `withRouter(InitStoreFromQueryString )`, however I ended up with component that simply renders nothing e.g.: `<InitStoreFromQueryString />` and simply dispatches actions on `componentDidMount`. This looks really awkward.

Is there a better way to achieve the same effect, i.e. initialize store based on query string params when application is loaded at startup?

Comment: I did the same thing. Did you ever find a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using react-router, you use the [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) module to track location changes. You can add a [listener](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#listening) to the history object, and dispatch an action when the location changes.

Example (not tested):

```
import createStore from "./store";
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

const store = createStore();
const history = createHistory();

const unlisten = history.listen((location) => {
  const accountId = extractFromLocation(location.search); // extract the accountId from the location query
  if(store.getState().accounts[accountId]) return; // if in store do nothing
  store.dispatch(updateAccountData(accountId)); // update the store with the new account
});
```